# Using two variables to assign one value using getters and setters

Tags: javascript

I did a Google search for [JavaScript getter setter](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20getter%20setter&oq=javascript%20getter%20setter&aqs=chrome..69i57.4224j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Here's the example for a getter:

```js
var obj = {
  log: ['test'],
  get latest() {
    if (this.log.length == 0) return undefined;
    return this.log[this.log.length - 1];
  }
}
console.log(obj.latest); // Will return "test".
```

And here's the example for a setter:

```js
var language = {
  set current(name) {
    this.log.push(name);
  },
  log: []
}

language.current = 'EN';
console.log(language.log); // ['EN']

language.current = 'FA';
console.log(language.log); // ['EN', 'FA']
```

Q: Is `log` just a coincidence? Because they're using console.log to output language.log.

Comment: So you're asking why some unknown person gave a specific property a specific name in some unknown situation?

Comment: `log` in `obj.log` is just an arbitrary property name. `console.log` is an API supported by many environments.

Comment: it is unwise to use reserved names or confusing names for variables. You could call the variable anything so why call it something potentially confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this.log` refers to `obj.log` and `language.log` respectively which is the array with that name that is defined inside of your custom object. It's just a coincidence that is named like the Console.log() method. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log

```js
var obj = {
  myProperty: ['test'],
  get latest() {
    if (this.myProperty.length == 0) return undefined;
    return this.myProperty[this.myProperty.length - 1];
  }
}
console.log(obj.latest); // Will return "test".
```

```js
var language = {
  set current(name) {
    this.myProperty.push(name);
  },
  myProperty: []
}

language.current = 'EN';
console.log(language.myProperty); // ['EN']

language.current = 'FA';
console.log(language.myProperty); // ['EN', 'FA']
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of `log` here is totally unrelated to `console.log`; in both cases, the underlying data model used by the setter or getter happens to be in a property called `log`. It could be called anything.

It's not a *total* coincidence that two different pages include examples with properties called `log`, however, because they were both authored by the same user on MDN, [Sevenspade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/profiles/Sevenspade):

- [Initial version of MDN's `set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set$revision/89110)
- [Initial version of MDN's `get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get$revision/27219)